# share data return from web api with sibiling component angular 2

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am new in angular. Currently using angular 5.I have 4 component one root component, inside root component there are two component child1.component and child2.component and inside child2.component there are another component child3.component. I have called a service on child1.component.ts file and display data on child 1 component my problem is i need  to display this data on child3 component. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Why don't you use the same service in `component 3` ?

Comment: Its not a good practice to call same service on different component.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty much the main reason services exist. What's the alternative? Do you want to create the same exact service for all your components?

Comment: there are some concept of sharing data between parent to child component , child to parent component and sibling component . I am able to share the data but my problem is  sharedata() method calls first after that i will receive data from json thats why i am not able to get data on child 3 component

Comment: pass the data through input property to child component.

Comment: I have tried to receive data using view child but problem is the event which receive data from child2 component in child4 component execute first then child2 component service executes. what is the solution in this senerio